# Is $1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\dots+\frac{x^n}{n!}$ irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

The polynomial $f(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\dots+\frac{x^n}{n!}$ often appears in algebra textbooks as an illustration for using derivative to test for multiple roots.

Recently, I stumbled upon [Example 2.1.6](http://books.google.com/books?id=b1a7ye_EjZwC&pg=PA51) in Prasolov's book Polynomials (Springer, 2004), where it is shown that this polynomial is irreducible using [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) and [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate). However, I do not think the argument is correct. Below you can find the argument presented in the book -- I do not see how Eisenstein is applicable here, since we do not know $p\mid n$. And if we are using Eisenstein's criterion directly to the polynomial $n!f(x)$, this is one of the coefficients that would have to be divisible by $p$. (However, the argument works at least if $n$ is prime.)

So my main question is about the irreducibility of the original polynomial, but I also wonder whether Prasolov's proof can be corrected somehow. To summarize:

> - Is the polynomial $f(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\dots+\frac{x^n}{n!}$ irreducible over $\mathbb Q$?
> - Is the Prasolov's proof correct or can it be easily corrected? (Did I miss something there?)

---

Here is the (whole) Example 2.1.6 from Prasolov's book. The same example is given in прасолов: многочлены(Prasolov: Mnogochleny; 2001,MCCME).

*Example 2.1.6.* For any positive integer $n$, the polynomial
$$f(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\dots+\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
is irreducible.

*Proof:* We have to prove that the polynomial 
$$n!f(x)=x^n+nx^{n-1}+n(n-1)x^{n-2}+\dots+n!$$
is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$. To this end, it suffices to find the prime $p$ such that $n!$
is divisible by $p$ but is not divisible by $p^2$, i.e., $p \le n < 2p$.

Let $n = 2m$ or $n = 2m + 1$. Bertrand's postulate states that
there exists a prime p such that $m < p \le 2m$.

For $n = 2m$, the inequalities $p \le n < 2p$ are obvious. For $n = 2m + 1$, we
obtain the inequalities $p \le n-1$ and $n-1 < 2p$. But in this case the number
$n-1$ is even, and hence the inequality $n-1 < 2p$ implies $n < 2p$. It is also
clear that $p \le n - 1 < n$. $\hspace{20pt}\square$

Comment: The irreducibility of these polynomials is due to Schur and uses prime ideal factorization in number fields. The proof in Prasolov's book is obviously bogus (for general $n$). I wrote up a correct proof at http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/schurtheorem.pdf. (By the way, the publisher name you give looks weird. The abbreviation they use in English is MCCME, not MCMO -- Moscow Center for Continuous Mathematical Education)

Comment: Thanks a lot @KCd, I'll have a look at the proof from your link. (I'll probably need some time to go through it.) Perhaps you could consider posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: Related post on MO: [Irreducible polynomial $p_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}$ for all positive integers $n$](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/240039/irreducible-polynomial-p-nx-sum-k-0n-dfracxkk-for-all-positive)

Answer (score 9):

"since we do not know $p∣n$."

I will take Keith's word for it that the argument, overall, is bogus.

However, please note that the condition Prasolov identifies as desired is

$$ p | n! $$ but not
$$ p^2 | n! $$

If $p \leq  n,$ then
$$  n! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \cdots (p-1) \cdot p \cdot (p+1) \cdots n$$
so indeed $p | n!$

If $2p \leq  n,$ then
$$  n! = 1 \cdot 2  \cdots (p-1) \cdot p \cdot (p+1)  \cdots (2p-1) \cdot (2p) \cdot (2p+1) \cdots n$$
so  $p^2 | n!$

If $p \leq n < 2 p$ then $n!$ is divisible by $p$ but not by $p^2$

EDIT: it is clear from comments that Martin was considering the entire Eisenstein argument, meaning that it is not enough to know the behavior of the last coefficient $n!.$ I did not have the Prasolov book in front of me and was late for an appointment, so I reacted strictly to the excerpt I saw on this site.

Comment: Yes, I certainly agree with what you wrote, we need $p\mid n!$ and $p^2\nmid n!$. This is fine. But we also need other coefficients to be divisible by $p$, i.e. $p$ should divide $n$, $n(n-1)$ etc. (At least if we apply Eisenstein's criterion directly to $n!f(x)$, without any tricks.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, sure. I'm just saying that Prasolov says he needs something about $n!$ and arranges that one thing. That is the excerpt you copied in from Prasolov. If his condition is still not good enough, that is another story.

Comment: That proof from Prasolov's book is in a section on the Eisenstein irreducibility criterion. Taking $n = 4$, his $4!f(x)$ is $x^4 + 4x^3 + 12x^2 + 24x + 24$. The only prime dividing $4!$ once but not twice is 3 and $4!f(x)$ is not Eisenstein with respect to 3. Prasolov never does any kind of additive translate, like replacing $x$ with $x+1$, so it sure seems like his proof is based on using Eisenstein's criterion directly on $n!f(x)$. The case $n=4$ shows this approach has problems (for nonprime $n$).

Comment: @KCd, Hi Keith. Makes sense to me. I probably would not have posted anything if Martin had written "Now, it is true that Prasolov's $n! \equiv 0 \pmod p$ while $n! \neq 0 \pmod {p^2},$ however Eisenstein's criterion also requires $p$ to divide these other numbers..." in which case we all, including beginning undergraduates, would be up to speed.

Comment: Do you prefer the Alice Cooper response or the Steven Tyler response?

Comment: @Asaf, tell me both, I do not believe I am familiar in either case. Meanwhile, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7pvy37XaRw

Comment: Well, this is a double Wayne's World (I & II) reference. Alice Cooper's response was to show his hand for them to kiss the ring; Steven Tyler exclaimed "You're worthy, you're worthy! Get up!".

Comment: @Asaf, thank you. I just noticed your profile quote here, wonderful: "I have no choice." And you say on MO you are doing set theory.

Comment: You may also note my reputation comes mainly from set theory, and in particular axiom of choice related questions (both here and on MO). I often say that forcing with large cardinals and no choice is a rich ground for puns.

Comment: I've tried to edit my question a little, to be more clear. I should have done so already when posting it. (But I think your answer + comments below it do a better job in clarifying my intentions.) I am grateful for your answer and for your time.